# javascript fileReader alternative for safari(<6)

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-io, safari

I'm developing a website that works offline(using cashe) on a client side.
I need to implement image upload to the LocalStorage via the website and then send it when the user will have access to the internet.
To read image as URL I use FileReader **BUT**
The problem is that most of the users will use Safari browser and there is no FileReader function in Safari(<6).

I read that it could be done via ajax post to a php script. The php script should echo back the content... but I need my website working offline so I think it's impossible to implement it via ajax.. Am I right?

how can I implement image reading in Safari browser?

Comment: You can't. Tell people to stop running browsers that don't get security updates any more.

Comment: @Quentin, I'm sure if that were an option he would do that. Qvatra, I think the answer I posted will provide what you're needing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

You'll also need to include the swfobject script in your page for Flash fallback to work properly, its a dependency of the FileReader polyfill. You can go [here](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to download the package.

**Previous:**

Here's a sample that demonstrates using the [FileReader](https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader) plugin. You'll need to use jQuery 1.x ([jquery-1.11.3.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js)) to achieve the desired backwards compatibility:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple>
<div id="list"></div>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.FileReader.min.js"></script>

<script>

$("#files").fileReader({
    filereader: "js/filereader.swf"
});

$("#files").on("change", function(evt) {

    for (var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {

        console.log(evt.target.files[i].name, evt.target.files[i].type, evt.target.files[i].size, evt.target.files[i].lastModifiedDate);

        var f = evt.target.files[i];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {

            return function(e) {

                // Render preview
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = '<img class="thumb" src="' + e.target.result + '" title="' + escape(theFile.name) + '"/>';
                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);

            };

        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);        

    }

});

</script>
```

**Previous**

You'll need to use a polyfill such as this [FileReader](https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader) plugin. It detects whether or not the user's browser has the FileAPI available, and if not, it uses Flash to emulate the now standard FileReader. Check out the documentation, but I'm fairly certain this is what you'll need.

I know you didn't have the question tagged with jQuery, but in order to use this polyfill it will be required, unless you're comfortable with adapting it to vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Hi thanks for this idea first of all, I am not comfortable with the documentation provided in the link, can you please explain it with a sample program? Please forgive my ignorance

Comment: @Geek Sure! I updated my answer with sample code demonstrating how to use the FileReader polyfill. Basically it allows you to use the FileReader functionality as if it's native to an older browser.

Comment: am getting "Can't find variable: swfobject" while page loading. can someone help me ?? thanks in advance

Comment: @dev I updated the answer. You'll need to include the swfobject script in your page for Flash fallback to work correctly. Let me know if this takes care of the problem.